# Bootstrap 4 - Avoid shrink navbar when scrooling up

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have following code and when I scroll up the navbar hide my text, keeping just icons. Is possible to change this behavior and avoid this "shrink"? How can I do that?

```
<nav class="d-md-none navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-bottom">
   <div class="col-4 text-center">
      <a href="{{ route('home') }}" class="text-white-50">
         <i class="fas fa-home"></i><br>Home
      </a>
   </div>
   <div class="col-4 text-center">
      <a href="{{ route('login') }}" class="text-white-50">
         <i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i><br>Login
      </a>
   </div>
   <div class="col-4 text-center">
      <a href="{{ route('register') }}" class="text-white-50">
         <i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i><br>Register
      </a>
   </div>
</nav>
```

[image: example]

Comment: working just fine to me. Do you have more code we could check like some CSS?

Comment: there are no errors, it is the default behavior, I would like to modify this default behavior applied by the fixed-bottom class (do not shrink the footer padding when scrolling up).